# SCORU securidty deposit

Tags: smart-rollup, scoru

I read a couple times in conversations that deploying a SCORU will cost 10k Tezos as security deposit.
But I cannot find it in the articles. Can you confirm that please?

Or does every L2 validator need to put in a 10k security deposit?

And lets say a dApp called XYZ runs on a SCORU. The dApp XYZ gets popular and need to scale up horizontally, so deploy more rollups. So when it comes for the 10k Tezos security bond:
If the dApp needs to deploy more sollups to scale up I assume that it needs to pay the 10k Tezos bond for every additional rollup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [documentation](https://tezos.gitlab.io/mumbai/smart_rollups.html#commitments) on Commitments. It is 10k.

Still, you wouldn't deploy more rollups to scale your dapp.

A "smart rollup" is a blockchain primitive like a smart contract, not actual infrastructure. Your job would mostly be focused on scaling the underlying infrastructure and making sure the whole deployment works effectively.

The throughput and TPS is then dependent on the infrastructure decisions and design that you make, and the storage limitations of the underlying L1. You can scale infrastructure independently without making new sr1 rollup addresses.

In short:

The **smart rollup** is your actual business logic that gives some output based on a series of inputs. This is data stored on the blockchain.

The **rollup node** is software that reads the Tezos blockchain, finds the L2 messages, then sends them as a series of inputs to your business logic, and come up with a resulting commitment. It costs 10k bond to post this resulting commitment to main L1 chain.

The **infrastructure** is whatever you come up with to run the rollup node software. Scale it horizontal or vertical. There are still L1 limits so you cannot scale infinitely. ([Data Sharding](https://research-development.nomadic-labs.com/tezos-is-scaling.html#next-level-scaling) is the future solution)

The 10k bond is more about ensuring that the commitment you post isn't a lie. If it is, someone else can stake 10k and post the correct commitment and slash your bond.

Comment: Thanks but in this Talk an engineer from Nomadic Labs said that you can just deploy more rollups if you want to scale: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sntF9MMicLs But maybe I understand the concept wrong, I will read the documentation you posted, thank you

Comment: Indeed, from the perspective of a DApp developer, a single rollup should be enough as the infrastructure running the business logic can be dimensioned according to the need. It is unlikely that a single DApp could need more than one rollup to handle its activity. In the context of the talk, we were taking the perspective of the Tezos blockchain where scaling the global throughput of the system is achieved by adding more rollups.

Comment: Ah ok thank you for clarifying!! Maybe its just me that I got it so wrong and mixed that up :) But maybe it would be good to clarify in s next Nomadic Labs blogpost and give an example from the Dapp developer point of view and then from the Tezos blockchain perspective so people can better distinct.